# Probability an interviewer gets her interviews

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

If an interviewer needs to interview 5 people, and each person has an independent probability of $2/3$ of accepting her invitation, what is the probability that she speaks to exactly 6 people given that she has a list of 8 people?

I though that this was answerable by the binomial distribution, namely $p=C(8,6)(2/3)^6(1/3)^2$ however, the book says the answer is $160/729$

How did the book get to that result?

Comment: But what the 5 people from the beginning have to do with it?

Comment: I think I might be able to enlighten you with my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by the way the answer is posed we understand we care not about which people we talked to. We only care about *how* many people we contacted.

So if she had to invite 6 people to be able to perform 5 interviews, it is because she invited someone who declined. Imagine you have an ordered list of people. The interviewer had to invite the first 6 people of that list in order to give 5 interviews.

Can you get the right answer now?

If $A $ means *interview accepted* and $D $ means *interview declined* then we want to count how many sequences of the type

$$AADAAA$$ there are, with the $D $ only being possible on some of the spots.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out (RSerrao too). She will stop contacting people if (1) she have interviewed 5 people or if (2) she reached the end of the list.

Anyway for this problem, length of the list isn't matter, I guess it's given to confuse you. In the first 5 calls she needs to have exactly one decline and at 6th call she needs to be accepted. ${5\choose 1}\frac 1 3 (\frac 2 3)^4\frac 2 3=160/729$